# Button calls function without being click

Tags: php, html, button

I have a button that class a php function, however it always calls the function whether the button has been clicked or not.

```
            <FORM>
            <INPUT TYPE="button"  VALUE="Dismiss" onClick="'.$this->dismiss_IE().'">
            </FORM>
```

On load I put an echo in the dismiss_IE() function which will show up and every page load.

How can I only call the dismiss_IE function when the button is clicked.

Comment: Please learn the difference between PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: I'm assuming `$this->dismiss_IE()` contains Javascript code, right? Can we see that code?

Comment: @Mr. Alien - I don't see why attacking me for making a mistake is helpful. I'm trying to teach myself through various examples and resources on the internet and unfortunately I mixed two languages up while doing so which is the root cause of my problem which I now know.

Comment: Ok people, we all had to start somewhere, keep the comments constructive.

Comment: @Nick I didn't attacked you, I asked you..I had no intentions to make fun of you, sorry if you felt bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your code. As @Mr. Alien said, you are trying to call a php function and it should be a javascript function.

```
<script language = "javascript">
function dismiss_IE() {
        //write javascript code instead of php
        //if you have php logics, try to use ajax to 
        // call the php page and write your logis there.
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="button"  value="Dismiss" onClick="dismiss_IE()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't call a PHP function in the onclick event. it will be evaluated as soon as the server reads your PHP code..